# the_title gives me the page's title not the post title in the following code

Tags: php, get-the-title

```
<?php
if(have_posts()){
    while(have_posts()){
        the_post();
        echo get_the_title();
    }
}
?>
```

this is my loop, really simple, im calling this within a custom page template i made called services, i expect the posts titles to pop up, but instead im just getting services.

Comment: You said it yourself.  You're in a page template.  If you create a loop in a page template and then echo `get_the_post()` it's going to give the page title.

Comment: but it doesnt make sense, why would a get_POST function give me the PAGE and not the post.

Comment: I agree, it's a bit confusing.  PAGES are actually just custom posts.

Comment: `get_post()` etc work on the global post object when no post is specified in the first parameter. When you're calling `have_posts()`, `the_post()`, etc, you're actually asking WordPress to use this global post. In the context of WordPress, Pages, Posts, and Custom Post Types are all "posts", just of different _types_. So, `have_posts()` is `true` because the page you're on _is a post_, just a post with the `post_type` of `page`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the default page loop and it will output the current page attributes like title or other. You should create your own loop with custon query instead. See [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).

Example

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'posta_status' => 'publish',
));

if($query->have_posts()){
    while($query->have_posts()){
        $query->the_post();
        echo get_the_title();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```